# Find Minimum sum such that no two elements are adjacent

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I have written this Code to find Maximum sum such that no two elements are adjacent, now I want to convert this Code into Find Minimum sum such that no two elements are adjacent using the same logic.

Please tell me how can I do it?

```
    #include<stdio.h>

/*Function to return max sum such that no two elements
 are adjacent */
int FindMaxSum(int arr[], int n)
{
  int incl = arr[0];
  int excl = 0;
  int excl_new;
  int i;

  for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
  {
     /* current max excluding i */
     excl_new = (incl > excl)? incl: excl;

     /* current max including i */
     incl = excl + arr[i];
     excl = excl_new;
  }

   /* return max of incl and excl */
   return ((incl > excl)? incl : excl);
}

/* Driver program to test above function */
int main()
{
  int arr[] = {5, 5, 10, 100, 10, 5};
  printf("%d \n", FindMaxSum(arr, 6));
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably not what you are looking for, but it is a good lesson about *reductions*: (1) Multiple all numbers by -1. (2) Run findMaximum

Comment: C# != C! Please pick one language and stick with it.

Comment: I'm not sure your code works correctly for finding maximum too, you must consider all the possibilities but you dont consider them.

Comment: Please provide him some solution

Comment: @user3264676 checkout the my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursion, with this strategy :

1. remove two last elements.
2. find minimum(maximum) sequence with your condition in current elements. I name it Sum2.
3. add last element to Sum2 in step 2 :

   - if the sum gets lower(higher for finding maximum) keep it otherwise dont add this to Sum2.
4. remove three last elements.
5. find minimum(maximum) sequence with your condition in current elements. I name it Sum3.
6. add element before the last element to Sum3 in step 5 :

   - if the sum gets lower(higher for finding maximum) keep it otherwise dont add this to Sum3.
7. compare sum2 and sum3 and you have your answer :)

for instance for finding maximum in your sequence : `{5, 5, 10, 100, 10, 5}`.

I reduce the sequence to `{5, 5, 10, 100}`

now maximum in this is : `5+100 = 105 = sum2`

then I add the last element to `sum2` so I have `sum2 = 110` and its bigger than `sum2` before so I keep it.

Now I reduce the sequence to `{5, 5, 10}`

the maximum is `5+ 10 = 15 = sum3`.

now I add the element before the last element to `sum3` and I have `sum3 = 10 + 15 = 25`. it is greater than before so I keep it.

now `sum2>sum3` so the biggest sequence is `5 100 5 = 110`

Answer (score -1):

A typical recurrence for your problem would be

> f(n) = max/min(arr[n] + f(n - 2), f(n - 1))

which can be solved in linear time using dynamic programming. To force taking the first element, just take it and consider the dynamic programming approach for the rest of the array.

A simple implementation would be the following:

```
int find_min(int arr[], int n) {
  int a = 0, b = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    int c = max/min(arr[i] + a, b); //Put max or min and it will work
    a = b;
    b = c;
  }
  return b + arr[0];
}
```

In this code, I store *f(n - 2)* in *a* and *f(n - 1)* in *b*. So in the end, *b* contains the answer.

I also think that you are doing the same in your code (not sure though), so if I am guessing correctly what you are doing, the following should work:

```
int FindMinSum(int arr[], int n)
{
  int incl = arr[1];
  int excl = 0;
  int excl_new;
  int i;

  for (i = 2; i < n; i++)
  {
     /* current max excluding i */
     excl_new = (incl < excl)? incl: excl;

     /* current max including i */
     incl = excl + arr[i];
     excl = excl_new;
  }

   /* return max of incl and excl */
   return ((incl < excl)? incl : excl) + arr[0];
}
```

Comment: Its not working   take 5,2,4,6,3,7 Output should be 5 , but its giving 0.

Comment: Why? You can sum 0 by not adding anything. Or are you forced to take the first element?

Comment: forced to take element.

Comment: With this edit it should force to take the first element. Despite that, then I think your solution for the maximum sum is not correct for the same reason. If you consider -5 -9, your solution gives 0, should be -5. The same trick I did to correct the min case should work for the max case.